# Decision Tree in python with sklearn change sklearn to use c4.5

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

My question is can we choose what Decision Tree algorithm to use in sklearn?

In user guide of sklearn, it mentions optimised version of the CART algorithm is used.

Can we change to other algorithms such as C4.5?

Answer (score 0):

According to scikit-learn documentation, they use an optimized version of the CART algorithm; however, the scikit-learn implementation does not support categorical variables.
Credit: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart